# iText iterating by word through pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to populate a datastructure that contains each words location in the PDF.

I have a PDF, and eventually I want to iterate through a data structure of the words and their locations.

something on the lines of:

     `a word "hello" is at rectangle (0, 0, 50, 50),
     a word "world" is at rectangle (50, 0, 100, 50)`

I know a word is meaningless in PDF, multiple text calls can happen (e.g. "hello" -> "he" + "llo" or "hell" + "o"). For my purpose that should be OK.

I'm not looking for efficiency here, so wierd workarounds are fine. My current thought is I can extract the text from the PDF, and then do a search for each word's location on the document (I know its horrible efficiency). How would I go about finding the location of a particular word in a pdf? Say, find the coordinates of the first occurence of "hello" in file.pdf

Comment: Basically, look at any example on Stack Overflow and elsewhere that uses a [LocationTextExtractionStrategy](http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy).

Comment: I cant find any... do you happen to have any links?